# Ehcache3 defaultCache-configuration equivalent

Tags: java, ehcache-3

In earlier versions of Ehcache you where able to define a default-cache configuration, which will be applied to caches created programmatically. Since Ehcache3 they changed the configuration xsd quite a lot and there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to defaultCache anymore - or at least, I cannot find it anywhere.

For example old configuration:

```
<ehcache
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
    updateCheck="false">

    <defaultCache 
        maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
        eternal="false"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="false" />
</ehcache>
```

I tried it with the following configuration, but I don't know if that is working or not or if I can just remove and ignore it. I guess I can ignore it because when I boot the application I don't get any warnings that ehcache cannot find a configuration for a specific cache.

New configuration:

```
<config
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core.xsd">

    <cache alias="default">
        <expiry>
            <ttl>120</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <heap>10000</heap>
    </cache>
</config>
```

The reason why I'm using `alias="default"` is because in this documentation: [ehcache.xml](http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xml) they mentioned that the internal name for defaultCache is "default". Quote:

> ```
> Default Cache configuration. These settings will be applied to caches
> created programmatically using CacheManager.add(String cacheName).
> This element is optional, and using CacheManager.add(String cacheName) when
> its not present will throw CacheException
>
> The defaultCache has an implicit name "default" which is a reserved cache name.
> ```

So the question is, is there an equivalent for defaultCache in Ehcache3 or can I just remove it?

Answer (score 2):

I tried your configuration with `<cache alias="default">`, and it didn't work for Ehcache 3.x. Ehcache still created new cache for missing cache with random default configuration.

What I found out is that they removed the feature of `defaultCache` in Ehcache 3.x. However, there is a feature of `Ehcache 3.x JSR-107 provider` and its configuration that allows the same function as `defaultCache`. You can see [here](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/blob/master/107/README.adoc) for more information.

Below is my Spring Boot configuration that allows default configuration for missing cache creation with Ehcache 3.x:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache        = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class   = org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.provider         = org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.uri              = classpath:ehcache.xml
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode     = ENABLE_SELECTIVE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics          = true
```

src/main/resources/ehcache.xml

```
<config
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
        xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'>
    
    <service>
        <jsr107:defaults default-template="myDefault">
        </jsr107:defaults>
    </service>

    <cache-template name="myDefault">
        <key-type>java.lang.Object</key-type>
        <value-type>java.lang.Object</value-type>
        <expiry>
            <ttl unit="seconds">300</ttl>
        </expiry>
        <resources>
            <heap unit="entries">1000</heap>
            <offheap unit="MB">10</offheap>
        </resources>
    </cache-template>
</config>
```